# type a recursice wrapper in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How would a function like this be fully typed?

```js
function wrap<A, B>(value: A, primitiveWrapper: <C>(value: C) => B<C>) {
    const type = typeof value;

    switch (type) {
        case "string":
        case "number":
        case "bigint":
        case "boolean":
            return primitiveWrapper(value);

        case "object":
            if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.map(v => wrap(v, primitiveWrapper));
            else return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(value).map(([k, v]) => [k, wrap(v, primitiveWrapper)]))

        default:
            return undefined;
    }
}
```

Comment: add usage example

Comment: It's basically impossible to type that properly because TypeScript doesn't have *higher kinded types* as requested in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213). They can be simulated, but it's really clunky, and involves a "registry" of such types that you can choose from.  If I use one of those simulation/workarounds, I get code like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ7prw).  Does that fully address your question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Answer (score 0):

```
type Primitive = string | number | bigint | boolean

type WrapRecurse<A> = A extends Primitive ? ReturnType<ABC<A>['callback']> : A extends (infer R)[] ? WrapRecurse<R>[] : A extends Record<string, unknown> ? { [K in keyof A]: WrapRecurse<A[K]> } : undefined

type Wrap = <A, B extends ABC<A>>(callback: A, primitiveWrapper: B extends never ? B : ABC<any>) => WrapRecurse<A>

// @ts-expect-error
const wrap: Wrap = (value, primitiveWrapper) => {
    const type = typeof value;

    switch (type) {
        case "string":
        case "number":
        case "bigint":
        case "boolean":
            return primitiveWrapper.callback(
                value);
        case "object":
            if (Array.isArray(value)) return value.map(v => wrap(v, primitiveWrapper));
            else return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(
                //@ts-expect-error
                value).map(([k, v]) => [k, wrap(v, primitiveWrapper)]))
        default:
            return undefined;
    }
}

type ABC<T> = { input: T, callback: (v: T) => T extends string ? null : T extends number ? undefined : T extends bigint ? string : T extends boolean ? number : never }

type PrimitiveWrapper = <T>() => ABC<T>

// @ts-expect-error
const p: PrimitiveWrapper = () => {

    return {
        callback: (a) => {
            const type = typeof a;
            switch (type) {
                case "string":
                    return null
                case "number":
                    return undefined
                case "bigint":
                    return "string"
                case "boolean":
                    return 123
                default:
                    throw ('something is wrong!!')
            }
        }
    }
}

const a = wrap('abc', p())
//    ^?

const b = wrap(123, p())
//    ^?

const c = wrap(0n, p())
//    ^?

const d = wrap(false, p())
//    ^?

const e = wrap(['abc', 123, 0n, false], p())
//    ^?

const f = wrap({ a: 'abc', b: 123, c: 0n, d: false }, p())
//    ^?

const g = wrap([{ a: 'abc', b: 123, c: 0n, d: false }], p())
//    ^?
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbtAvFAzsRAOwHMoAfKQgVyQCMI5ypaFiFDgnaB7bgGwgBDQgCgRoSFADqcQWABKEAMZU4uCAB4AggD4oOLVAgAPYBEIATXLEQo0mKAH4oi4KsIAVcJq0AhAMLaOgDaAORKgnx8tIJKANahALp6AFxQhiZmltYAFOwAZgwuAJTBiU7SsgrKquoa8iHlaRmm5lYuytxwFhr4RMQANFBUhHGE3ADuhHrOAN5QwQDSUOxQcRAg3PnpiWkycooqaj5LyVAAvlBpIxYQ+ewQFmIS0Ptg+lDaQ75GrdnpASCOhyESiMXizSGYFsqAwEDekDgaR+mTa1kIEEwjGcP2agOEIB0xX0ejeh1qPh0YgA9NSoAABYC4AC0JkgSmArLgcC6IiU3EI+CgEyqeyqHxy6EiVAgUJh9nhVURxKwelmIigmqg-MFnBeHxeWygUr4MoA3GItXgJqglAALKA5F7E9VWq0RdRQABEfXYxC9KQ1bs1HugXuodAYAaDwdD3pYbA40eDIcEnq9PH4QkIyZTVrgEDccEIUGhyFhmARDAAdKDorE4jkY3m3SaZcULXm417uLQAFbKYC5lsrbY5LTcwQgasIXAT2QgSXSiDFYkFosltsQatIOSSknCqqSuXlhVVuCrzsjox8T3r9xQADy-cH1fyPKQAFEOIgILgcs+A4ctW5gEAgf5Ntebq0oyLJsoOXI8nAzZQVuxQ7nuOTBHEQzoIkKp6NhQwinu6AnnYcLnsU+HFChWq3PkghUHwwCBlB97FsMlh3A8FhXpq5wiIJ4jeACgQeHoODzOwYBUKxUAeEMdbgnEaSSmkHgEQpvxZO0vokBU1BRFc2mov8Eb0NiXEMbxJkeDpaLMKw7CcM4+mkBpDn-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)

This is a very difficult problem

The real problem is not the recursion, the real problem is how to pass the type of `value` to `primitiveWrapper`

**Because you need to consider the possibility of `primitiveWrapper` being a generic function that may transform your type** (this is totally depend on your use case of course)

**Hence `primitiveWrapper` must aware of the type of `wrap`'s `value` in order to calculate proper output type**

In my example, `primitiveWrapper` transform `string` to `null`, `number` to `undefined`, `bigint` to `string`, `boolean` to `number`

and this is the result:
[image]

as you can see, it works, you may further test it

**Important: this methods despite produces correct result, it is janky. You need to suppress the type error when you declare functions with type `Wrap` and `ABC`! Which mean you are on your won to make sure the runtime is correct, I recommend you do both test and type test to ensure the correctness**

*thing would be easy if we just allow `p` to accept argument same value as `value`, so instead of `p()`, we do `p(123)`. But in here I want to prove that it is possible without accepting any argument.*

now if you want to change the code to fit your need, these are the parts you can change, because they are part of example

[image]

The bigger question is, what is going on?

Unfortunately, I know the how but not the why, someone please show me the patch note!

This is what I deduced:

1. generic `A` of `Wrap` infer the type from `value`
2. `input`'s `T` of `ABC` read the type from `A` (this is surprising, return's type parameter can infer type from generic of the other function, what?!)
3. generic `T` of `ABC` infer the type from `input`'s `T`
4. then `callback`'s`T` read the type from `ABC`'s `T`